# Opening .jar files on Gnome Desktop

Tags: java, linux, centos, desktop-application

I've installed gnome desktop and window x on centos, the only problem I have now is opening .jar files on my desktop. How do I open them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean running by opening, just use the command

`java -jar <jarfile>`

If you want to extract the contents of a jar file, just use the command

`tar -xvf <jarfile>`

Comment: Thanks! But I'm getting `Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException:                                                                    
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.` When I run it.

Comment: Put those lines 
`DISPLAY=:0.0
export DISPLAY` 
to your /home/username/.bash_profile file.

Comment: are you sshing into this machine? Does it have X11 forwarding enabled? if you are using ssh, try `ssh -X` which should force the X11 display to be set if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Open up a command line console, cd to the directory where the jar file resides, and use

```
tar -xvf <jarfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

yup, even the graphical interface allows this with the same tool is uses for unzips.  Name of it escapes me at the moment though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `FileRoller` is the name of the default GUI for archive files in GNOME. Extra libraries might be needed to make it work with jars by default, not sure.

`tar` works too from command line. But just in case you are interested in a gnome GUI option...